# Ignore all parameters in binding except those excplicitly specified in actions signature

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a web api controller like:

```
public  HttpResponseMessage MyAction(string param1, string param2)
{
//do whatever
}
```

If i have requests like 
Controller/MyAction?param1=a&param2=b 
its all well and good.

But if i have something like 
Controller/MyAction?param1=a&param2=b&excessParam=c

then i get that no action was found. I understand its due to web api binding rules/priorities.

What i am interested in is if there is some way of simply ignoring all parameters submitted in request except those explicitly specified in controller action signature?

ps.
not talking about optional params as i still have to specify them in actions signature.

i understand it is a bit against nature of web api bindings and i am sure it can potentially cause problems of overlapping/ambigious bindings but i am just curious if there is some solution to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if i have something like
>   Controller/MyAction?param1=a&param2=b&excessParam=c
>
> then i get that no action was found.

No, that's not quite true. You will get a 404 if you do not provide some of the *known* parameters:

```
Controller/MyAction?param2=b&excessParam=c
```

Excess parameters are ignored by the Web API and will not cause you any troubles.

In order to avoid those 404 errors you could make those parameters optional:

```
public IHttpActionResult MyAction(string param1 = null, string param2 = null)
{
}
```

Alternatively write a model containing the *known* parameters:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Param1 { get; set; }
    public string Param2 { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public IHttpActionResult MyAction([FromUri] MyModel model)
{
}
```

Comment: not sure what to say but i can assure you that if i provide all known params and one excess param that is not in method signature the message i get is: 'No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI '

Comment: I am not assured because I have just tested that and my service worked without any issues, no matter what excessive query string parameters I throw at it. Maybe there's some custom code or model binder in your solution which is behaving like that, but that's not the case in an out-of-the-box ASP.NET Web API project. Just create a new Web API project and try it for yourself. So now the question you should be asking yourself is where is this custom code located in your solution so that you can try to fix it there. By the way did you try the view model approach I suggested?

Comment: hm...that is strange. not saying you are wrong, just wondering why it doesnt work on my side. let me do some tests here to see if something else in the pipeline screwing it up.

Comment: Also I hope I understand your question correctly: you are asking about ASP.NET Web API, right? Because your question is tagged with asp.net-web-api but in your example you are showing some ASP.NET MVC controller action, you know, the one that returns an `ActionResult`.

Comment: Why without a view model? It's so much cleaner, and it will definitely unclutter your action signatures.

Comment: right right, its web api not mvc. i was typing signature from my head and put actionresult. but its web api

Comment: You were right, omitting some of the required parameters in action signature results in 404. Excess parameters are ignored by default. There seemed to be some problem with my machine at the moment when i was testing it as it was returning 404 even when i had all required parameters but added some excess (which really doesn't make too much sense). Anyways, restarting the machine solved it.
Thank you, i am marking your answer!